# Set a maximum windowsize in a MacOS SwiftUI App

Tags: macos, swiftui

I try to define the maximum windowsize in a MacOS SwiftUI App like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var width = 400.0
  
  var body: some View {    
    VStack{
      GeometryReader { geometry in
        VStack {
          Text("Suggested Width : \(width)")
          Text("Width           : \(      geometry.size.width)")
          Text("Height          : \(      geometry.size.height)")
          Button("Set width to 200"){
            width = 200.0
          }
        }
        .padding()        
      }
      .frame(maxWidth: width)
    }    
    .background(Color.green)
  }
}
```

The **.frame(maxWidth: width)** only affects the "inner" green VStack.
The (MacOS)Window can be dragged bigger than the maxWidth.

How can I define the maximum Width for the (MacOS)Window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.windowResizability` in the `App` struct on the `WindowGroup` Scene.
If you set it to `.contentSize` it derives min and/or max values of the window size from the view sizes inside the window.

```
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .frame(minWidth: 100, maxWidth: 400, minHeight: 100, maxHeight: 400)
        }
        .defaultSize(width: 400, height: 400)
        .windowResizability(.contentSize) // here: this takes min and max sizes from the child view.
```